# Unexpected Boolean behavior of Python's xml.etree.ElementTree leaf elements

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I am experiencing some trouble using the Python 2.6.5 xml.etree.ElementTree library. In particular, if I setup a simple xml element like the following

```
>>> import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree
>>> xml = etree.fromstring("<a><b><c>xy</c></b></a>")
```

i have no problems with the library when accessing the inner element nodes, e.g.:

```
>>> etree.tostring(xml.find('b'))
'<b><c>xy</c></b>'
>>> xml.find('b') == None
False
>>> bool(xml.find('b'))
True
```

However, I am encountering a strange boolean interpretation of leaf element nodes, see:

```
>>> etree.tostring(xml.find('b/c'))
'<c>xy</c>'
>>> xml.find('b/c') == None
False
>>> bool(xml.find('b/c'))
False
```

Note that in the last command, the element *xml.find('b/c')*, which is clearly non-None, evaluates to *False*. This is especially annoying since i cannot use the idiom

```
>>> leaf = xml.find('b/c'):
>>> if leaf:
>>>     do_stuff(leaf)
```

to check whether a leaf element exists. (I have to check explicitly for *'xml.find('b/c') != None'*.)

Can someone please explain this (for me unexpected) behavior?

Comment: Addendum: I am not asking for other other Python libraries to handle xml, I just want to understand the behavior of the given library package.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, sorry, after submitting this question I found the explicit statement of the solution in the Python documentation: http://docs.python.org/release/2.6.5/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#the-element-interface , at the end of the section.

> Caution: Because Element objects do not define a **nonzero**() method, elements with no subelements will test as False.

Sorry for the inconvenience.